# extjs:can not drag element over IFrame on Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, iframe, extjs, drag-and-drop, extjs4

My test code is showed below:

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({enabled:true});
Ext.Loader.setPath("Ext.ux", "http://cdn.sencha.io/ext-4.2.0-gpl/examples/ux");
Ext.require("Ext.ux.IFrame");
Ext.onReady(function()
{
    new Ext.container.Viewport(
    {
        items:
        [
            {
                xtype:"label",
                text:"Drag Source",
                style:"background:black;color:white;padding:20px",
                listeners:
                {
                    afterrender:function()
                    {
                        this.dragZone = new Ext.dd.DragZone(this.el,
                        {
                            getDragData: function (e)
                            {
                                var sourceEl = e.getTarget();
                                if(sourceEl)
                                {
                                    var d = sourceEl.cloneNode(true);
                                    d.id = Ext.id();
                                    return{
                                        sourceEl: sourceEl,
                                        ddel: d
                                    };
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                xtype:"uxiframe",
                width:"100%",
                height:"100%",
                src:"http://google.com"
            }
        ]
    });
})
```

When the label drag over onto the "uxiframe", the "Ext.dd.DragZone" will not work.
But it works fine on other browsers such as Opera and Chrome.

Thank you for any help in advance!